# How to get jquery array in html input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to get a jquery array into a html input and I can't figure out where I am wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="datepicker" name="dates[]" />
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
$('#datepicker').datepick({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    multiSelect: '100'
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#butto").click(function() {
        var dates = $('#datepicker').datepick('getDate');
        console.log(dates);

        $('#datepicker').val(dates);
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
$dates= $this->input->post('dates');

foreach($dates as $datee) {
    print_r($datee);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting value to this ` var dates ` variable ?

Comment: Which datepicker library are you using?

Comment: If you use a lib the question is not "How to get jquery array in html input" but "How can I use %LIB_NAME% to add data in my input". Tell us the lib name or check the documentation :)

Comment: @SilentCoder no i am not getting any value in print_r($datee);. That is the problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html#getDate this one. but i am getting array in console.

Comment: In Java the array values passing from front-end to the server by creating multiple input types with the same name each contain single value server will convert it as an array nicely. I think that will apply here also.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly get the dates array, because the multi select dates are passing by comma(,) separated by default. So you need to do small hack before submitting the form data. Bellow is the self defined code to achieve the result.

**jQuery Code**

```
<script>
    $('#datepicker').datepick({

      dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      multiSelect: '100',

      //convert the selected date into array and assign the value to your hidden filed when the date picker will close by any format

      onClose: function(dates) { 
         var selectedDate = []; 
         for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) { 
             selectedDate.push($.datepick.formatDate(dates[i])); 
         } 
         $('#datepicker').val(JSON.stringify(selectedDate));
      },

   });
</script>
```

**PHP Code**

In the server side catch the hidden filed value and decode it using json_decode function to get the array of dates.

```
$dates= json_decode($this->input->post('dates'));

foreach($dates as $datee) {
   print_r($datee);
}
```

Hope it will work as your expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 // if $dates = ['2018-10-9','2018-10-10']
$dates= $this->input->post('dates');
if(count($dates)!=0){
  $isDate = "";
  for($i=0; $i<=count($dates); $i++) {
    $isDate .= $dates[$i].',';
  }
  $isDate = rtrim($isDate,',');
  print_r($isDate);
  // will return $isDate = "'2018-10-9','2018-10-10'";
} else {
  print_r("no dates");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the Answer. 
**HTML:**

```
*<input type="hidden" id="datepicker1" name="dates[]" />*
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
$('#datepicker').datepick({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    multiSelect: '100'
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#butto").click(function() {
        var dates = $('#datepicker').datepick('getDate');
        console.log(dates);

        *$('#datepicker1').val(dates);*
    });
});
</script>
```